# Cleanly shutting down a warp server without exiting the process

Tags: yesod

I am looking at using wai/warp for some custom interprocess communications. This would have the unusual requirement that I would need to start/stop warp instances dynamically within a process. The main issue seems to be cleanly stopping warp. This question is addressed here:

[How do I implement a shutdown command in a WAI server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881327/how-do-i-implement-a-shutdown-command-in-a-wai-server)

but the suggested solution end up exiting the process by returning from main. Can I just throw a ThreadKill exception to the warp thread?

This thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yesodweb/VoenrabRUBQ

suggests that an IORef could be passed on startup, which could trigger a shutdown externally. This sounds ideal, but isn't part of the current API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run Warp in a separate thread via `forkIO` and then kill that thread only.

Comment: That is what I am doing currently. Can I rely on the internals of warp being cleaned up correctly?